# Java - for loop currentTimeInMillis() - BlueJ

Tags: java, bluej

I'm learning Java at the moment, i'm using BlueJ to write a method that returns currentTimeInMillis() while y < 100. At the moment i'm receiving an error stating "missing return statement". Any suggestions re the error/code?

```
import java.lang.System;

public class Math
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private int y;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Math
 */
public Math()
{
    // initialise instance variables
    y = 0;
}

/**
 * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
 * 
 * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
 * @return     the sum of x and y 
 */
public static long currentTimeMillis()
{
    // put your code here

    for (int y = 0; y<100; y++)
    {return y;
    }

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to add a return statement in the end:

```
public static long currentTimeMillis()
{
    // put your code here
    for (int y = 0; y<100; y++)
    {
      return y;  // This code does not make sense as it will always return 0
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // from the function name it appears you want to return current time millis

    return System.currentTimeMillis();

}
```

Comment: :) Im still quite new at this, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Your `currentTimeMillis` is supposed to return a long. This signature

```
public static long currentTimeMillis()
```

states that your *private*, *static* method, must return a value of type *long*.

You, the coder, can assume that the for loop will always be executed, but the compiler can't, this is why you have to add a `return` statement at the end of the method. I'd refactor the whole method though...

Comment: Thanks, the purpose is to return and print currentTimeinMillis while it is less than 100. How would you propose writing the method?